# "graphicsmagick identify" results in error "Backing store not supported " for a lot of jpegs, how to fix?

Tags: gimp, graphicsmagick

I'm using a [tool](https://thumbsup.github.io/docs/) to generate a photo album from my photo collection.
This tool uses GraphicsMagick under the hood to generate thumbnails of the photos. Unfortunately , GraphicsMagick gives an error on a lot of photo's to get its properties, e.g.:

```
gm identify ./building.jpg
```

gives the following error:

```
C:\program files\graphicsmagick-1.3.42-q16\gm.exe identify: Backing store not supported (./building.jpg).
C:\program files\graphicsmagick-1.3.42-q16\gm.exe identify: Request did not return an image.
```

I have the feeling that it has something to do with GIMP as well, as it mostly happens on photos that were postprocessed using GIMP.

- What does this error mean? I cannot find any pointer in the [GraphicsMagick  FAQ](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/FAQ.html)
- Is the image corrupt? It appears normal in any photo viewer. The file I'm testing is [building.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/edj6rvfydbopxv9ei3hv7/building.jpg?rlkey=rtxuwz0qyc1pm7vcr2lzhz5d3&dl=0)
- Is there a way to get more debug output grom GraphicsMagick?